# Haskell interact() truncating my output?

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming

I'm working on a basic Haskell program which contains this line of code:

```
interact (unwords . (map pigLatin . words) )
```

However, after passing the array of strings to my pigLatin function, then wrapping back into a string, it always truncates the last word I enter. For instance:

```
*HaskellPractice> getUserInput
this is broken
histay isway
```

For some reason it is not printing that.
I am on a Mac, so I have the following options declared in getUserInput before the call to interact:

```
hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

I'm guessing it's a small detail that I have yet to fully understand. Thanks for any input/help!
OSFTW
EDIT: Here's the whole program.

```
    import System.IO

pigLatin :: String -> String
pigLatin word = if ( (head word) `elem`['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] )
    then (word ++ "way")
        else  (tail word) ++ [(head word)] ++ "ay"

getUserInput = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering

    interact (unwords . (map pigLatin . words) )
```

Comment: Can you post a complete program that replicates the problem? Are you typing Control-d at the end of your input when you run it from ghci?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! I updated the OP. And yes, I'm pressing control-d

Answer (score 2):

Here is the program I tested:

```
import System.IO

pigLatin xs = "[" ++ xs ++ "]"

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  interact (unwords . (map pigLatin . words) )
```

And here is what a `ghci` session looks like:

```
*Main> :main
this is line1
[this] [is] this is line2
[line1] [this] [is] [line2]<stdin>: hGetBuffering: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

I typed:

```
this is line1
this is line2
(Control-d)
```

So it's not truncating the input - it's just not emitting the last word in the line until the next line is read (or EOF is encountered.)

If you run it from the shell you get what you expect:

```
shell$ (echo this is line1; echo this is line2) | runhaskell  ./platin.hs

[this] [is] [line1] [this] [is] [line2]
```